# Can I use MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf<Int>()) launch a Flow collect?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know I can change the `state` with `mutableStateListOf` in Code B.

Can I use `MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf<Int>())`  launch a Flow collect in Code A?
If not, is there a similar Flow function just like `mutableStateListOf` ?

**Code  A**

```
val stateFlow = MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf<Int>()) 

stateFlow.value.add(1)
stateFlow.value.add(2)
```

**Code B**

```
val listExpandedMInfoID = mutableStateListOf<Int>()
listExpandedMInfoID.add(mInfo.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StateFlow breaks if you use it with any mutable class, including MutableList. It cannot detect a change in the list so it will not emit the list again if you mutate it.

There is no Flow analog of `mutableStateListOf()`. If you use StateFlow, you have to use read-only Lists for it to work. With other flows, you could use a mutable list but you would have to emit it again each time it’s modified.

List copies are not expensive anyway unless your List is enormous.